# if statement not working

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have an app where there is a timer. It goes from 10 to 0. Using NSTimer. I have said:
.m:

```
//
//  Skin.m
//  PopThatPimple
//
//  Created by Rohan Kapur on 6/2/11.
//  Copyright 2011 UWCSEA. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Skin.h"


@implementation Skin
@synthesize theAudio;
@synthesize label;


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:pimple];
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(pimple.bounds, point) ) {
        [self checkcollision];
    }


}




-(void)checkcollision {


    pimple.center = CGPointMake(
                                random() % (unsigned int)theview.bounds.size.width, 
                                random() % (unsigned int)theview.bounds.size.height

                                );

score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([score.text intValue] + 1)];



    sad.hidden = NO;

    NSURL* popURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pop" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) popURL, &popID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(popID);




}




// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/




-(void)showActivity{

    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + -1;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector (showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [label2 setHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];


}


-(void)void2 {



if ([label3.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) { 
        [[self view] addSubview:timeup];
        score.text = label2.text;
        label2.hidden = NO;

    }

}
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


@interface Skin : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *pimple;


IBOutlet UIImageView *smile;
IBOutlet UIImageView *sad;
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
IBOutlet UIView *theview;
SystemSoundID popID;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face2;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face3;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face4;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face5;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face6;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face7;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face8;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face9;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face10;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face11;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face12;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face13;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face14;
IBOutlet UIImageView *face15;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
IBOutlet UILabel *score;
IBOutlet UIImageView *skin;

    IBOutlet UILabel *time;
    NSTimer * myTicker;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
    IBOutlet UIImageView * timeup;
}
-(IBAction)start;
-(void)void2;
-(void)showActivity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain)AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
-(void)checkcollision;



@end
```

I have not used all of my outlets and ibactions yet. And i have not used avfoundation yet
I have CONNECTED EVERYTHING! I HAVE CHECKEED A THOUSAND TIMES! When it reaches zero nothing happens and the timer just goes to the negatives. WHat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two major problems here, the first is you're using an assignment operator, not a comparison operator, I'd imagine you have a warning on that.

The second is an `==` comparison is useless here, the fixed code would be.

`if ([label3.text isEqualToString:@"0"])`

Comment: Would need to see more context about what is going wrong. You have some really...odd...code there

Comment: You need to format the code better, read the instructions on posting. Also when I said more, I meant some context, or a specific piece. Not the whole project.

Comment: You have to put your answer in the void you call for the NSTimer, at least thats the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second (third?) what @BoltClock and @Joshua Weinberg wrote, but add that checking the text displayed in a label is a poor way to determine whether a timer has expired. At some point, somewhere in your program, you're *setting* the label's text to @"0", so you already *know* that that condition is true. Likewise with the score... your controller should *know* what the score is, and it definitely shouldn't be relying on a label to get it.

*Don't store data in your view objects.* Data should flow from your model through your controller to your view. It only flows in the opposite direction when you're accepting user input.

Comment: How does label3's text get set to @"0"? How does -void2 (lousy name for a method, btw) get called? What makes you think that -void2 is ever called when label3's text is @"0"? What, for that matter, makes you think that label3's text ever exactly matches @"0"? What have you done in the debugger to examine the problem?

Comment: I found it out. I forgot to call the void in the NSTimer

Comment: You have to put your answer in the void you call for the NSTimer, at least thats the easiest way.